# Composition of PartialFunctions in Scala

Tags: scala, akka

I'm working with akka actors. All actors should implemented the `receive` method, which has a signature of `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`. I want to define a stricter function to use for the matching with signature like `PartialFunction[Action, Unit]`. However, this doesn't compile:

```
class PlayerActor extends Actor with {
  override def receive: Receive = rec

  def rec: PartialFunction[Action, Unit] = {
    case Jump() =>
  }
}
```

I want to do this so the compiler will warn me if I forget a case.

`Receive` is defined as `type Receive = PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`

---

I ended up doing it manually like:

```
override def receive = {
  case a: Action => rec(a)
}
```

It can also be done by casting:

```
override def receive = rec.asInstanceOf[PartialFunction[Any, Unit]]
```

Or via an implicit conversion:

```
implicit def toAnyPartial[T](f: PartialFunction[T, Unit]): PartialFunction[Any, Unit] =
  f.asInstanceOf[PartialFunction[Any, Unit]]
```

Comment: Take a look at [typed actors](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/scala/typed-actors.html)

Comment: That's right.  You can't restrict the types of messages sent to untyped actors.

Comment: Looking at TypedActors is quite probably not what is asked for here; it is completely reasonable to handle only a specific subset of all possible messages without restricting which messages may be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to create `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` using implementation of type `PartialFunction[T, Unit]` you could try this:

```
implicit def toPfAny[T](pf: PartialFunction[T, Unit]): PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
  object PF { def unapply(a: T): Option[Unit] = pf.lift(a) }
  { case PF(_) => () }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> def impl: PartialFunction[String, Unit] = { case s => println(s) }
impl: PartialFunction[String,Unit]

scala> def receive: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = impl
receive: PartialFunction[Any,Unit]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this

```
def rec: Receive  = { case a: Action => a match {
  case Jump() =>
}}
```

Comment: senia: that's what the caller asked for.

Answer (score 1):

`PartialFunction` is contravariant on its first type parameter. I shall not dig into explanation what this means (there are books, blog posts, SO questions & answers), but will give you very trivial example instead.

You are allowed to pass `Any` to `receive`. If it would be possible to assign `rec` to `receive`, it would mean you may pass `Any` to `rec`, thus bypassing `rec`'s type. Compiler prohibits it.

Comment: There is `isDefinedAt`, so it's not a problem.

Comment: @senia Exactly. Maybe I was asking too much for the compiler to make some magic with `isDefinedAt`...

Comment: Well, the declaration `PartialFunction[-A,+B]` says it all.

Comment: @EmilIvanov: You can create your own magic. Just define implicit conversion from `PartialFunction[T, Unit]` to `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`.